What is the formula to calculate crossover altitude and speeds?
Indicated airspeed, (IAS) will always correspond to a certain Mach number at any altitude.  If a targeted IAS or Mach number is desired for a climb or descent, at some altitude the pilot will crossover from flying with reference to either the IAS or Mach number, depending on whether the aircraft is in a climb or descent.
How do you calculate the altitude where a target IAS and Mach number correlate with one another?

The optimal IAS for climb or descent as well as the optimal Mach number is typically calculated by the FMGC on the A320 based on the entered cost index.
The pressure altitude at which these values correspond to the same TAS can be calculated from the following formulas (see also this answer):
$$ M = \sqrt{5 \left[ \left( \frac{q_c}{P} + 1 \right)^{2/7} - 1 \right]} $$
$$ \text{CAS} = a_0 \sqrt{5 \left[ \left( \frac{q_c}{P_0} + 1 \right)^{2/7} - 1 \right]} $$
with $q_c$ as impact pressure, $ a_0 \approx 340.3 \, \text{m/s} $ as sea level speed of sound and $P_0 \approx 101 \, 325 \, \text{Pa} $ as sea level pressure.
Flying at a fixed CAS implies flying at a fixed impact pressure $q_c$, which can be calculated by resolving the second equation for it:
$$ q_c = P_0 \left( \left[ \frac{1}{5} \left( \frac{\text{CAS}}{a_0} \right)^2 + 1 \right]^{7/2} - 1 \right) $$
To find the altitude where the impact pressure is the same in both formulas, we can solve the first equation for pressure $P$ and plug in our known $q_c$:
$$ P = \frac{q_c}{\left(\frac{1}{5} M^2 + 1\right)^{7/2} - 1} = P_0 \frac{\left( \frac{1}{5} (\text{CAS}/a_0)^2 + 1 \right)^{7/2} - 1}{\left(\frac{1}{5} M^2 + 1\right)^{7/2} - 1} $$
This pressure can then be converted to an altitude, e.g. using the ISA to get pressure altitude. Plotting this for different values of CAS and Mach gives this:

With typical values for the A320 of CAS 290 kt and Mach 0.78, you would get a crossover somewhere at FL309. The crossover is typically shown on a plot like this, where the TAS of both cases is compared:


Glossary:

IAS: Indicated Airspeed
CAS: Calibrated Airspeed (on the A320: equivalent to IAS since CAS is already shown on the PFD)
TAS: True Airspeed
FMGC: Flight Management and Guidance Computer
ISA: International Standard Atmosphere


And… a handy close approximation for calculating P from baro altitude, H (in ft) is:
for H = SL to 36,089 ft:
P = P_SL(1 - 6.87535E-6H)^5.265
and for H = 36,089 to 65,617 ft:
P = P_SL0.22336e^(-4.80634E-5(H - 36,089))*

A side note on the limitations of air data systems... source, position, and other error corrections can be applied to the sensed pressures that are quite good. However, accuracy is never always 100%. A typical aircraft level requirement is to get reported CAS within 1-3 knots of actual. Sometimes these requirements vary by flight condition.
